# How many bits is the access flags of a file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, ext3, ext2

How many bits on a linux file system is taken up for the permissions of a file?

Comment: Do you literally mean the traditional permissions bits, or do you care about other permission-like metadata?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add to the other answers:

Traditional Unix permissions are broken down into:

- read (`r`)
- write (`w`)
- execute file/access directory (`x`)

Each of those is stored as a bit, where 1 means permitted and 0 means not permitted.

For example, read only access, typically written `r--`, is stored as binary `100`, or octal `4`.

There are 3 sets of those permissions, which determines the allowed access for:

- the owner of the file
- the group of the file
- all other users

They are all stored together in the same variable, e.g. `rw-r-----`, meaning read-write for the owner, read-only for the group, and no access for others, is stored as `110100000` binary, `640` octal.

So that makes 9 bits.

Then, there are 3 other special bits:

- setuid
- setgid
- sticky

See `man 1 chmod` for details of those.

And finally, the file's type is stored using 4 bits, e.g. whether it is a regular file, or a directory, or a pipe, or a device, or whatever.

These are all stored together in the inode, and together it makes 16 bits.

Comment: After I was confused by this [blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-the-nine-permissions-bits-on-files/) about linux file permissions I almost wanted to ask about it in UL-SE but lucky I found your explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Which permissions?  Basic permissions fit in 16 bits; ext2 uses 32 bits, plus another 32 bits for file flags (`chattr(1)`); then POSIX ACLs use variable space in addition.  See `/usr/include/linux/ext2_fs.h` for details.  (ext3 and ext4 build on ext2 and mostly use the same structure.)

Answer (score 4):

Information about files are stored in a data structure called an inode. There is a field in this structure for the mode, which contains the permissions. This field on my system is an unsigned short which is 2 bytes and 16 bits.

Take a look at fs.h in the Linux source to see for yourself.